# How to format a date in java?

Tags: java

How can change this date format "2011-09-07T00:00:00+02:00" into the "dd.MM." i.e "07.09."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you searched "How to format a date in java?" on internet or even on this site? I don't think so..

Answer (score 7):

here is a sample

edited the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String input = "2011-09-07T00:00:00+02:00";
    SimpleDateFormat inputDf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat outputDf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM");

    Date date = inputDf.parse(input.substring(0,9));
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(outputDf.format(date));
}
```

Comment: I will be getting the above mentioned date format as an input from XML file and I need to convert it into "dd.MM"

Comment: @neha check the new code for your requirement. If you don't understand it, try debugging the code in eclipse. You should be able to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Basically -

1. Create a date format object from the above string
2. Parse into a date object, and reformat however you prefer.

For example (I haven't tested this):

```
/*
 * REFERENCE:
 * http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/
 */
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatExample1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Make a new Date object. It will be initialized to the current time.
        DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date d = dfm.parse("2011-09-07 00:00:00");

        // See what toString() returns
        System.out.println(" 1. " + d.toString());

        // Next, try the default DateFormat
        System.out.println(" 2. " + DateFormat.getInstance().format(d));

        // And the default time and date-time DateFormats
        System.out.println(" 3. " + DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(d));
        System.out.println(" 4. " +
            DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(d));

        // Next, try the short, medium and long variants of the
        // default time format
        System.out.println(" 5. " +
            DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(d));
        System.out.println(" 6. " +
            DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(d));
        System.out.println(" 7. " +
            DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG).format(d));

        // For the default date-time format, the length of both the
        // date and time elements can be specified. Here are some examples:
        System.out.println(" 8. " + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
            DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT).format(d));
        System.out.println(" 9. " + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
            DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT).format(d));
        System.out.println("10. " + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
            DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG).format(d));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first format string is incorrect - months are MM, not mm.

Comment: ... and you are missing the 'T' and the timezone segment of the date/timestamp.

Comment: I will be getting the above mentioned date format as an input from XML file and I need to convert it into "dd.MM"

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs a little correction on the following line

```
Date date = inputDf.parse(input.substring(0,9));
```

In place of `(0,9)` you need to enter `(0,10)` and you will be getting the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2011-09-07T00:00:00+02:00" ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM" )
```

## java.time

The Question and other Answers use old legacy classes that have proven to be troublesome and confusing. They have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Your input string is in standard ISO 8601 format. These formats are used by default in java.time classes. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2011-09-07T00:00:00+02:00" );
```

You can generate a String in your desired format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM" );
String output = odt.format( f );
```

## `MonthDay`

You want month and day-of-month. There is actually a class for that, [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html).

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.from( odt );
```

You can generate a String in your desired format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM" );
String output = md.format( f );
```